# Custom input filter accepts Numeric Value in regex

Tags: java, android, regex

```
public class FilterActivity implements InputFilter {
Pattern pattern;

public FilterActivity(int beforeDecimal) {
    pattern=Pattern.compile("([0-9]{0,"+(beforeDecimal-1)+"})?");
}

@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int end, Spanned spanned, int spanstart, int spanend) {
    Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(spanned);
    if(!matcher.matches()){
        return "";
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

When changing or editing the field it accepts a, 2a  I need only accepts 0-9

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new FilterActivity(3)});
```

I know the property in android **"number Decimal and number"**, but I try to achieve this problem using Regular expressions.

Comment: Try `"^([0-9]{0,"+(beforeDecimal-1)+"})?$"`

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @horcrux EditText accepts Firstletter accepts any value and A number followed by a char accepts all value when change the edittext (For Example It can accepts 1a ,1  .   :   etc... )

Comment: Try this to change like this `FilterActivity implements DigitsKeyListener implements InputFilter` instead of what you are using.

Comment: @Tim editext accepts number and minimum length without using the the property inputType="number||numberDecimal"

Comment: @NitinPatel  , That also not working

Comment: @pskink It also accepts alpha and special chars

Comment: @Raj What are you returning when pattern matches?

Comment: @NitinPatel  not handle that, if pattern not match then returns empty

Comment: @pskink That is handle the functionality of limits and i'm also tried your solution

Comment: @Raj **Updated** Then try to change `return null;` last line with `return new SpannableStringBuilder(charSequence, start, end);`.

Comment: @NitinPatel not working

Comment: beforeDecimal it's just a variable

Comment: its used for length of the edittext   Use this then the edittext maximum accepts the beforeDecimal

Comment: @pskink  I'm not familiar in regex  but i know something about regex. And Thanks for your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @horcrux but I think since your multiplier starts at 0, you can omit the "?":

```
"^([0-9]{0,"+(beforeDecimal-1)+"})$"
```

And if you don't need to catch the result, you can even omit the parentheses:

```
"^[0-9]{0,"+(beforeDecimal-1)+"}$"
```

But you will need the anchors (^ and $) to indicate, that there may be nothing to the left or right of the match.

@Raj if I understand your answer to @horcrux correctly then you have optional letters after the digit?
try:

```
"^([0-9]{0,"+(beforeDecimal-1)+"}[a-z]?)$"
```

or:

```
"^([0-9]{0,"+(beforeDecimal-1)+"}[a-zA-Z]?)$"
```

if they can also be upper case

Comment: Ya! the problem is occur in android  that's way i'm attach my android code ... Thanks for explain regex..

Comment: Heiko Are you well expect in python

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    public class FilterActivity implements InputFilter {
      public FilterActivity(int beforeDecimal) { }

      @Override
      public CharSequence filter(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int end, Spanned spanned, int spanstart, int spanend) {
           for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
               if (!Character.isDigit(charSequence.charAt(i))) {
                     return "";
               }
            }
            return null;
     }
}
```